# Timeout exceeded when trying to pull hello-world image on wsl2 windows10

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I install wsl2 (ubuntu 20.04) on my windows system and I am having troubles with docker. I am not able to run simple hello-world image because I get following error:

`Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)`

I configured resolv.conf by adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 because I've read that this helped some people but it didn't work for me.

My version of docker:

```
 Version:           20.10.9
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.8
 Git commit:        c2ea9bc
 Built:             Mon Oct  4 16:08:29 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.9
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.8
  Git commit:       79ea9d3
  Built:            Mon Oct  4 16:06:37 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.11
  GitCommit:        5b46e404f6b9f661a205e28d59c982d3634148f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

I tried to restart docker - `sudo service docker restart` but it also didn't help.

I am out of ideas how to fix this. Can anybody help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I started getting this error on a Centos 7 server.  The cause was wrong proxy settings: the network team of my company removed the need for a proxy and I checked that no `HTTPS_PROXY` env variable was set on the server but in my case the proxy setting for Docker was in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` as described [in this page](https://www.sbarjatiya.com/notes_wiki/index.php/HTTP_proxy_configuration_for_Docker_on_CentOS_7).

BTW, I also tried updating Docker but `yum` didn't work either: it has its own proxy settings in `/etc/yum.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem happend to me too.
I found this article helpful.

https://serverfault.com/questions/908141/docker-pull-tls-handshake-timeout

It provides temporary solution, like `docker pull ${IMAGE}` separately.

It helped me.

P.S. This error is not common, it may be caused from time to time, so don't spend too much time on it :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm behind a proxy server. Additional to setting proxy in system env var, I have to also set the proxy in docker daemon (like @Pino 's answer above)
In docker version > 23, you can also set it by https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/